Excel - Adding a number to numbers containing text
I have a cell G64 containing text A100
I want to add a value of 1 to the number 100 within the text while perserving the text "A" in the result, such that the result would be A101 in a new cell.
I have tried the following formula
=CONCAT("A",SUM(1,VALUE(RIGHT(G64,FIND("A",G64)+2))))

which does result in A101. However, is there a quicker or more efficient way of doing this in Excel ver. 2021?

There are more elegant ways of doing this to resolve, however not sure will it be always a single character text or multiple characters if so then, you could try the following:


• Formula used in cell B1
=LET(
     α, MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),
     δ, ISERR(--α),
     ε, 1+CONCAT(FILTER(α, 1-δ)),
     φ, CONCAT(FILTER(α, δ)),
     Σ, φ&ε,
     Σ)


And If the character is one single then :


=LET(a, A1, b, LEFT(a), b&RIGHT(a,LEN(a)-LEN(b))+1)


One more possible way using LET()+LOOKUP():


=LET(
     α, -LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)))),
     SUBSTITUTE(A1,α,)&α+1)



Nice approach. The first formula is not correct for "A1S202" (AS1203) while the last one works correctly (A1S203).

You can try a shorter formula such as:
="A" & MID(A1, 2, LEN(A1)-1) + 1

Or this if you wish to be more flexible:
=LEFT(A1,1) & (MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-1)+1)


Shorter formulas already presented might be sufficient for your need, but here's an alternative:
Assuming the values are comprised of letter(s) followed by digit(s),
=LET(
    input, A2,
    first_pos_of_digit, XMATCH(
        TRUE,
        ISNUMBER(--MID(input, SEQUENCE(, LEN(input)), 1))
    ),
    prefix, LEFT(input, first_pos_of_digit - 1),
    number, RIGHT(input, LEN(input) - LEN(prefix)),
    prefix & number + 1
)



Hello another way to solve this in Excel 2021 if we don t know the exact number of characters before the numbers:

=LEFT(A1,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),""))-1)&1+MID(A1,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),"")),255)+0
Hope it helps.
